# Goland does not recognise my vendor directory with Go 1.14

Tags: go, goland, go-modules

When I open my Goland project, the following command is run:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14/libexec/bin/go list -m -json all #gosetup
```

Its output is the following error:

```
go list -m: can't compute 'all' using the vendor directory
    (Use -mod=mod or -mod=readonly to bypass.)
```

Goland cannot resolve the packages I'm importing.
When I build and run the project from the command line, it works fine.

My project is structured as follows:

```
app/
    bin/
    pkg/
    src/
        app/
            cmd/
            vendor/
            go.mod
```

My `GOROOT` is `/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14/libexec` and my `GOPATH` is `app/`.

In Goland settings, under Go/GOPATH have checked the boxes for "Use GOPATH that's defined in system environment" and "Index entire GOPATH".

Under Go/Go Modules (vgo), I have checked "Enable Go Modules (vgo) integration" and "Vendoring mode"

I have just noticed when I change the `GOPATH` to `/Users/myname/sdk/go1.13.4`, the problem is solved. Could this be an issue with Homebrew or a change introduced with go 1.14 that I am not aware of?

I'm being exhaustive when describing the issue because I'm unfamiliar with Go and might be missing something obvious.
Thanks!

Comment: Saves my day. Now the Goland 2020.1 is out and has automatic vendoring mode support, https://www.jetbrains.com/go/whatsnew/#go-114-support

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a known problem with Go Modules and vendoring support due to tooling change in Go 1.14.

As such, please try the EAP version of the IDE, https://jetbrains.com/go/nextversion, which contains a fix for this.

We are tracking this under https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-8855 and thinking about backporting this to the 2019.3 release cycle.

Comment: Since i’m using the Jetbrains Toolbox, it was as simple as enabling EAP, i presume this will allow me to go back to stable releases in the future. 

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can use the EAP version in parallel with the stable version. You can read here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/tag/2020-1/ about what features to expect from 2020.1

Comment: Is there a workaround for older versions like 2019.1? My license expired and can't upgrade to latest version.

Comment: No, sorry. Please reach out to the Sales team and maybe they'll be able to help you out with the upgrade to 2020.2.

Answer (score 3):

Disabling Go modules integration in Goland works for me

File->Preferences->Go->Go Modules->Enable Go modules integration

Comment: This was annoying me and this was a quick fix

Comment: same happened with me unchecking that checkbox, fixed the issue

Comment: This doesn't work with vendoring enabled, e.g. `go mod vendor`